# "callback is not defined" in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is part of my code, and it doesn't work. It says,

ReferenceError: callback is not defined
    at C:\js\kweb-hw\routes\board.js:14:13

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql_db = require('../db/db_con')();
var pool = mysql_db.init();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err,conn) {
        if(err) {
            if(conn) {
                conn.release();
            }
            callback(err,null);
            return;
        }
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM board";
        var exec = conn.query(sql,[] ,function(err, rows) {
            conn.release();
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('board', { rows: rows });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `callback(err,null);` – There is no `callback` defined by your code. So the error message is very accurate.

Comment: did you even TRY debugging this?

Comment: It's even giving you the line number...

Comment: Define callback function somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a callback in this case, because you're at the end of your route, so to speak.

So instead, you could do something like handle it with sending an error message to your rendered page.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql_db = require('../db/db_con')();
var pool = mysql_db.init();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err,conn) {
        if(err) {
            if(conn) {
                conn.release();
            }
            res.render('board',{rows: [],error:'Could not connect'});
        }else{
          var sql = "SELECT * FROM board";
          var exec = conn.query(sql,[] ,function(err, rows) {
              conn.release();
              if (err) throw err;
              res.render('board', { rows: rows });
        });
      }
    });
});
```